# phpinfo displays date.timezone warning in MAMP

Tags: timezone, mamp, php

I ran a phpinfo() function in MAMP, and received the following warning, embedded in the php info table:

```
Warning: phpinfo() [function.phpinfo]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EST/-5.0/no DST' instead in /Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/phpinfo.php on line 2
```

the date.timezone in the php.ini file is set to 'America/New_York', and the warning is only three rows above that actual setting reflected in the phpinfo table!

Could someone please explain to me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Check the path of your php.ini, sometimes, the php.ini you do use is not the same if it is on cli or on web.

Comment: Thank you @artragis! Where can I find the path to the php.ini that MAMP is actually using?

Comment: in cli you can use php --ini , on web, use phpinfo() function and it will says you.

Comment: I checked. It's the correct php.ini. Moreover, the actual phpinfo SHOWS that the date.timezone is set at the correct value. However, it still shows the warning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're certain there are no quotes around the timezone in the .ini file?

date.timezone = America/New_York

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php#85815

Comment: thank you. I tried it with single quotes, double quotes and no quotes, and restarted the server each time, and still, I get the same warning. It's supposed to be with quotes, isn't it?

Comment: No. According to the documentation, it's no quotes in the .ini file, but double quotes when declared in a script, which you might try as well, if you have a 'global' .php include file somewhere that all of your pages are pulling.

Comment: Well, as I said, I tried with or without quotes, single and double, to no avail, the warning remains. Would appreciate more insight.